# Estilo de fonte do googlefont funciona em localhost mas não no gdrive

Tags: google, font

Os dois estilos de fonte Sans narrow e Wire One do google fonts não funcionam quando eu publico no Gdrive, porém só funciona em local host. Estou chamando as fontes pelo método de chamada de link externo, sem ser pelo estilo font face. Segue abaixo o printscreem do erro no firebug e aonde era para ser a fonte, se alguém puder solucionar o problema eu agradeço[image: Fonte funcionando em local host]  [image: Erro firebug]

Answer (score 0):

Você está encontrando um erro de conteúdo misto (CORS) - no seu caso, carga de dependências via HTTP a partir de uma página carregada via HTTPS.

Altere os links das chamadas para as fontes de

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=tipo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

para

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=tipo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Excluindo a especificação de protocolo (`HTTP` / `HTTPS`). O browser então decidirá qual protocolo utilizar a partir do protocolo utilizado para carregar a página inicial, evitando assim o erro de *mixed content*.